# Unable to retrieve data from my sql database using pymysql

Tags: mysql, python-3.x, database, pymysql

I have been trying to retrieve data from my database. I was successful, however, this time inside an if statement. The code looks like:

```
cur_msql = conn_mysql.cursor(cursor=pymysql.cursors.DictCursor)
select_query = """select x,y,z from table where type='sample' and code=%s"""
cur_msql.execute(select_query, code)
result2 = cur_msql.fetchone()
if(result2==None):
    insert_func(code)
    select_query = f"""select x,y,z from table where type='sample' and code='{code}'"""
    mycur = conn_mysql.cursor(cursor=pymysql.cursors.DictCursor)
    print(select_query)
    mycur.execute(select_query)
    result3 = mycur.fetchone()
    if(result2==None):
         result2=result3
```

Now I see that insert_func does successfully insert into the 'table'. However, on trying to fetch that row, immediately after the insertion, it returns `None` as if the row is absent. On debugging I find that result3 is also `None`. Nothing looks wrong to me but it's not working.

Answer (score 0):

you don´t execute it in the right way, in the cur_msql.execute, you the to send the query and a tuple of values, and you are sending just a value:

```
cur_msql = conn_mysql.cursor(cursor=pymysql.cursors.DictCursor)
select_query = "select learnpath_code,learnpath_id,learnpath_name from contentgrail.knowledge_vectors_test where Type='chapters' and code=%s"
cur_msql.execute(select_query, (meta['chapter_code'],))
result2 = cur_msql.fetchone()
```

Comment: If the row is present in the table, result2 is not none. If it is not present only, it is none. For that reason, I have kept the if condition. So, it works with the way I send before the if statement. However, inside the if statement, after a successful insert, the data retrieved is none despite having just inserted it.